# issue in searching uppercase string with wildcard

Tags: solr, wildcard

I am using solr search. my search field contains both `diamond` and `Diamond`.
But when i search for `Diamond` or `diamond` it gives me correct results. But when i search for `Diamond*` or `diamond*`, I get result for `diamond*` but no results found for `Diamond*` . although i have applied  `<filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>.`

would you please suggest me what can be the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Unlike other types of Lucene queries, Wildcard, Prefix, and Fuzzy queries are not passed through the Analyzer, which is the component that performs operations such as stemming and lowercasing"

http://wiki.apache.org/lucene-java/LuceneFAQ#Are_Wildcard.2C_Prefix.2C_and_Fuzzy_queries_case_sensitive.3F

Inside this link there's the workaround for this problem

Comment: ya i got the point that wild card queries does not pass through the analyzers but as in my docs i have "Diamond" keyword than when i search for Diamond* it should search for Diamond..is not it ??

Comment: Nope, the wildcard locks the token, so it doesn't run throu the lowercase filter

Comment: :Than what can i do so it should show me the result for Diamond if i query as Diamond*

Comment: I tried to reproduce this in Solr 4. It looks like, the default behavior in wildcard query is NOT case sensitive. So diamond* and Diamond would bring up the same result

Comment: The Bndr : its not like that as i mentioned in my post i ma not getting result for Diamond* but ya i am getting result for Diamond

Comment: http://lucene.apache.org/java/2_3_2/api/org/apache/lucene/queryParser/QueryParser.html search for LowerCaseExpandedTerms, this is the method you need to perform lowercase search with wildcards, i think you have to implement your own plugin (in java) and use it with your default search handler

Comment: +1 this answers the question nicely.  @Romi its in the documentation Samuele provided.